# send callerid to ruby app in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

i have a ruby app with for post something as arg to my web server
for example:
i want to send phone number for adding in my database
i use this command

```
ruby /home/test.rb 123456
```

now
i want to send callerid with asterisk
in my extension.conf in set this commands

```
exten => 111,1,NoOp(${CDR})
exten => 111,2,System(ruby /home/test.rb "${CDR(clid)}")
exten => 111,3,Dial,sip/111
exten => 111,4,Congestion
```

but nothing send to my ruby file
help please

Comment: Try with full ruby path

Comment: i try it and also i'm include path in rb file and executable rb file but asterisk do nothing!

Comment: If I can make a suggestion, don't use the CDR function for this. You may get the right value - but you're re-purposing a billing function for party identification, which could some day have unintended consequences. You may want to use the CALLERID function instead, which is the correct function for getting the party information from a channel.

Answer (score 1):

1) Always use full path in System() command

2) for more control use AGI command.

3) Note, that asterisk will run script as user "asterisk". So ensure your script have no issues with permissions( like can't write log etc)

Comment: yes,i have a problem with rvm and asterisk user, and i bulid ruby again without rvm then my script work well